# Why isn't my styling being applied to a custom toast class?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, styles, toast

I want to create a customized Toast when click on a div with ionic 2, I've add a cssClass when create the toast on my ts file but the css won't be applied. **here is my code :**

**notification.ts :**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the NotificationPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-notification',
  templateUrl: 'notification.html',
})
export class NotificationPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {
  }

  ToastNotification() {
    const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'User was added successfully',
      duration: 100000,
      position: 'top',
      dismissOnPageChange: true,
      cssClass:  "custom-toast"

    });

    toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
      console.log('Dismissed toast');
    });

    toast.present();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad NotificationPage');
  }

}
```

**scss**

```
.custom-toast {
            background-color: red;
            text-align: left;
        }
```

any help please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your toast styles to the *app.scss* and it will work.

example:

app.scss

```
.my-toast {
  .toast-wrapper {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: when i set background-color: red , a full div above the content colored with red like this :  http://hpics.li/eb42395

Comment: can you please tell me how to inject and  html tags on the toast itself ?

Comment: What r u trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I'm trying to add other texts and images into the toast

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do it, I think you will probably have to overwrite the toast component. I googled it and found this:
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426051/how-to-create-or-customize-a-toast-view-using-ionic2-framework

2. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-toast-how-can-i-include-image-in-my-message/65317/4?u=alberick0

Hope this help you.

Comment: When you build using --prod the toast doesnt show up because of the styling, any fix for this? im doing 'ionic cordova build android --prod'

Comment: Its not working for me, iam using ionic 5.x